# Session is closed Exception

Tags: mysql, hibernate, struts2, spring-3, c3p0

I am building an application with Struts 2 hibernate spring 3 with my sql as back end and c3p0 connection pooling(c3p0-0.9.1.1 jar).

Sometimes, when executing a query, I get the below error. When ever I am executing query I check if the connection is closed or not, and if it's closed I will open a new connection before executing the query.  I'm providing the stack trace that i got. Please help me to get through this

```
Apr 16, 2013 18:01:32  505802 [http-apr-80-exec-3] INFO  com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor - Session is closed!
org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getBatcher(SessionImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1801)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
    at com.tcs.ignite.junoon.abstractclasses.AbstractService.find(AbstractService.java:207)
    at com.tcs.ignite.junoon.abstractclasses.AbstractService.find(AbstractService.java:169)
    at com.tcs.ignite.junoon.services.MasterSchoolService.getAllSchoolList(MasterSchoolService.java:30)
    at com.tcs.ignite.junoon.actions.user.AddPerson.setupRequiredMaps(AddPerson.java:239)
    at com.tcs.ignite.junoon.actions.user.AddPerson.execute(AddPerson.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
    at com.tcs.ignite.junoon.interceptors.LoginCheck.intercept(LoginCheck.java:46)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1770)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

```
public List<T> find(final Query query, final Object[] values) throws HibernateException, NullPointerException {  
        if (values != null) {  
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {  
                query.setParameter(i, values[i]);  
            }  
        }  
        List<T> resultList = null;  
        if (hibernateSession == null || !hibernateSession.isOpen()) {  
            try {  
                openHibernateSession();  
                resultList = query.list();  
            } catch (Exception e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            } finally {  
                closeHibernateSession();  
            }  
        } else {  
            resultList = query.list();  
        }  
        return resultList;  
    }
```

---

```
public List<T> find(final String queryString, final Object[] values) throws HibernateException {  
        if (hibernateSession == null || !hibernateSession.isOpen()) {  
            openHibernateSession();  
        }  
        Query queryObject = hibernateSession.createQuery(queryString);  
        return find(queryObject, values);  
    }
```

---

```
private void openHibernateSession() throws HibernateException {  
    try {  
        hibernateSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();  
        hibernateSession.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);  
        hibernateTransaction = hibernateSession.getTransaction();  
        hibernateTransaction.begin();  
    } catch (Exception e) {    
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  

}
```

---

```
private void closeHibernateSession() {  
    try {  

        if (hibernateTransaction != null) {  
            hibernateSession.flush();  
            if (!hibernateTransaction.wasCommitted()) {  
                hibernateTransaction.commit();  
            }  

        }  
        if (hibernateSession != null) {  
            if (hibernateSession.isOpen()) {  
                hibernateSession.close();  
            }  
        }  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
}
```

---

```
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projectdb</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>  
    
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>  
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>   
    
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">50</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">2</property>  
    
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies">true</property>  
    <property name="connection.pool_size">20</property>  
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>  
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>  
    
    <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">4</property>
```

Comment: It's likely that you can get a better response if you also post the code around the place where the error occurs.

Comment: @JennyD infact its not occurring in one place. I occurs randomly when i execute some query. I get exception on different query each time i test. And it only occurs when i am hitting with simultaneous users. This time i got only once when i hit with 20 concurrent users.

Comment: I was thinking about the part of the code that checks whether the connection is open and opens a new connection if necessary.

Comment: @JennyD Actually am doing that when ever I execute query. Still i get the exception

Comment: I understand that you do that whenever you execute a query. I'm trying to say that if you show **how** you do that, it might be useful for someone wanting to help you.

Comment: @JennyD I added the code for opening and closing session please go through it and provide me with you valuable suggestions

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to save or update a transient instance make sure the entities associated with instance are persistent. This is a common error of users trying to persist a new instance of the entity with the detached references. Get the entity from the persistence context before you set its reference to the transient or detached instance that you are going to persist.

Comment: Currently I am getting this error not only in save or update. When ever i tries to fetch some data then also am getting this.

Comment: Then you have messed connection configuration. the connection is closed when you fetch some data. Post your c3p0 and hibernate properties.

Comment: I added the code part where i am getting the exception Please check and provide me with valuable suggestions

Comment: If you manually manage the session per thread then you should close it after transaction. You didn't in the second find. I can't see if it used or not and how did you implement the session concept, can't see.

Comment: In the first find you may execute query with closed session. Format the code so, I could see where the code breaks.

Comment: Infact I am calling the first find from the second find. and in first find I am closing the transaction. so i think i dont need to close it again in the second

Comment: @Raoman I added the hibernate and c3p0 configurations as u suggested. Please go through that also.

Comment: No, here you mistaken, do it after each find and remove `else {  
            resultList = query.list();  
        }  ` from the first find

Comment: infact I am opening and closing the the sessions and transactions in actions. I added the the opening of session to my find method because i used to get the session closed exception more frequently before. I started my project by using full hibernate plugin for  injecting my transactions and session. But moved to manual injection because of the frequent session closed exceptions.

Comment: @user1850594 this code is the root cause of the exception you have

Answer (score 0):

you can probably fix your most immediate problem pretty easily. have your closeHibernateSession() reliably set hibernateSession to null. that will force your query functions to create new Sessions rather than try to reuse an old, closed session.

**but don't just do this. you have much bigger problems.**

you need to be much cleaner in how you organize your hibernate sessions. from the code above, it's clear that you have a member variable called hibernateSession that may be shared by across multiple callers or by multiple queries, that is sometimes null and sometimes not, which various functions lazily initialize but may not close until some time down the line. that's no good at all.

in the simplest arrangement, don't hold the session as a member variable. hold it as a local variable. let openHibernateSession() return a session that will be closed with perfect certainty in a finally block. if for some reason you need sessions to outlive what can be encapsulated by a single function call (which might of course call many other functions, each of which might take the session as a parameter), you will have to be very, very careful. sessions that are open must reliably be close()ed, and you must understand their lifecycles. your current approach, which uses a session if one is already open, but creates a temporary session otherwise, is no good. if you insist on maintaining a Session member variable, you must know with perfect certainty, whenever the member variable will be initialized, exactly how and when it will be close()ed and then reset to null or dereferenced for garbage collection.

you also should understand your transactions, none of this "if i have an uncommitted transaction before close(), commit it."

also, please consider migrating to c3p0-0.9.2.1