# JSP Input data (Welcome.Jsp) cannot get by Java code (OrderProcessingAction.saveOrUpdate() )

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2

JSP page input the details user and sends to struts action, `struts.xml` mapped the action to Action class `OrderProcessingAction` method `saveOrUpdate()` and this method call `saveOrUpdateUser()` of DAO class where actual data accessing the DB tables fields.

Below are deliverables:

1. JSP Page **:** Welcome.jsp
2. ActionClass **:** OrderProcessingAction.java
3. Data Access **:** UserDaoFactory.java Object
4. `struts.xml` file

```xml
/**
 * Welcome.Jsp : Here my JSP page code.
 */
<s:form method="post" name="myform" action="saveOrUpdate.action">
                   
    <s:textfield label="Customer Name" name="username" size="30"/>
    
    <s:password label="Customer Password" name="password" size="30"/>
    
    <s:textfield label="Contact No" name="contact" size="30"/>
  
    <s:textfield label="Email" name="email" size="30"/>
   
    <s:textfield label="City" name="city" size="30"/>

                       
    <s:submit label="Submit" />
    <s:reset label="Clear"/>

</s:form>
```

Here `struts.xml` file.

```xml
<action name="saveOrUpdate" 
        class="com.view.OrderProcessingAction" 
        method="saveOrUpdate">
 <result name="success">/Welcome.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Below is my OrderProcessingAction (ActionClass) where i'm getting call of DAO class method.

```
private String username;
private String password;
private int contact;
private String email;
private String city;
    
//Pojo class OrderPorcessing reference initiated
OrderProcessing user = new OrderProcessing();   

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}   
public int getContact() {
    return contact;
}
public void setContact(int contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
    
  /**
  * To save or update user. 
   * @return String
  */
   public String saveOrUpdate(){
            
    userDaoFactory.saveOrUpdateUser(user);
    System.out.println("User Name: " +user.getUsername());
    return SUCCESS;
  }
```

Below saveOrUpdate method from DAO class.

```
     /**
     * Used to save or update a user by saveOrUpdate().
     * @return void
     */
      public void saveOrUpdateUser(User user) {
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx = session.getTransaction();
         
        session.saveOrUpdate(user);
        
        tx.commit();
        session.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you have jumped on strut, hibernate and all the heavenly framework without getting your basic, like JSP and application server interaction, cleared. Though you are not alone in this. Most of the people are pushed into SPRING STRUT thing without even first getting to know their essence. To the extent that some novice think that an application can't be designed without these framework. I will suggest to you to do more research on basic like Request object, Session object and then learn the wrapper designed over them.

Comment: yeah!Thanks for correcting:) But everything I said, I still stand by it.

Comment: @mawia : I understand that you given a right guide to me. Yes, I'm novice. I'm not getting values in user reference. I know i'm wrong in somewhere in getting these values. Let me know where my shortfall is.

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing this

```
System.out.println("User Name: " +user.getUsername());
```

do this

```
System.out.println("User Name: " +getUsername());
```

Comment: But user Object/reference doesn't hold the form input values. So DAO class cannot hold the user object data.

Comment: as i see your code, with every request a new object of your action class gets created which causes the instance variable user to get reinitialized again, Now when the call reaches the saveorupdate method the user reference is nothing but a new object that is being created in the first line of your action class, and thus there is no form data available to this object.
In case you want the form data, please dont initialize the user and in the jsp instead of providing username in the name attribute provide user.username.
This will surely put the form data in the user reference.

Comment: So instead of 
OrderProcessing user = new OrderProcessing(); 
Should i write only,
OrderProcessing user;

Comment: yes, and provide the getter and setter for user...also map the form field with user.username and user.password instead of just the username, password etc

Comment: No, It'll give an error : attempt to create saveOrUpdate event with null entity. Because if user not initializa hoe it will store the values.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you should replace DAO to a [typical transaction](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html)

> A typical transaction should use the following idiom:
>
> ```
>  Session sess = factory.openSession();
>  Transaction tx;
>  try {
>      tx = sess.beginTransaction();
>      //do some work
>      ...
>      tx.commit();
>  }
>  catch (Exception e) {
>      if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
>      throw e;
>  }
>  finally {
>      sess.close();
>  }
> ```

Comment: As i know struts.xml file i state 
<action name="saveOrUpdate" 
        class="com.view.OrderProcessingAction" 
        method="saveOrUpdate">
 <result name="success">/Welcome.jsp</result>
</action> 

So saveOrUpdate method will call insted of execute(), vbecause if i haven't defined in method action tag than it default take execute() method. In my case i defined to redirect it saveOrUpdate() of action class.

Comment: Other buttons also `saveOrUpdate` executed?

Comment: Nope But delete and other actions doing great with same mapping styles.

Comment: Ok, your action is mapped great but how about transaction management? However `.action` not required.

Comment: Sir, my application running smothly, and i think i'm not having problem with any mapping. .action or without both work well. 
The actual problem may be with every request a new object of  action class gets created which causes the instance variable op to get reinitialized again. And the time i use saveOrUpdate() the new reference initiated in action class. So null values printed.

Comment: However, you are absolutely wrong without any doubt the `<s:form` tag doesn't accept `.action` extension in the `action` attribute. hah, fellow removed my answer with his question. Ok, another one with the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054362/session-is-closed-exception/16054717#16054717

Comment: And you don't posted the code for `OrderProcessing` is it a user you want to save or update? And you not referencing the instance that could be your action implement a `ModelDriven` interface?

Comment: OrderProcessing is POJO class.